# How to place elements on top of each other

Tags: css

I have a `<button>` with 3 spans in it - each span containing different text.  At different times, triggered by Javascript, the class of the button will change.  Using CSS transitions & transform, I have one span moving out of the button, and another moving in.  That all works.

The problem is that the button has grown to the full width of span 1 + span 2 + span 3.  I want the width to be simply large enough to contain the largest of the spans.  If all the spans could be placed one on top of the other, this would work.

I can't figure out how to get the 3 spans to sit one on top of the other.

Here's a fiddle showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/V9yTs/  (Click the button to see the change)

**Edit** Here's the final, working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XW3DY/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution for layering your spans on top of each other would be to use `position: relative;` (which I see you already have there) and then modify the top margin of spans 2 and 3 so that they move up to the same position as the span 1.

Here's an updated version of your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XW3DY/2/


(Please note that floated elements cannot be placed on top of each other. This is why relative positioning is generally used for placing elements of top of one another.)

Comment: Thanks!  That did it.  I played around with position:relative, but just couldn't get it to work.  I think the margin-top did the trick.  It seems strange to me that margin was the attribute that made it all work.  Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: Just for your edification - I optimized the CSS down to 24 lines from 61: jsfiddle.net/XW3DY/7/

Answer (score 0):

Since you already use jQuery, you can just calculate the proper width and height

```js
var w = 0;
$('.btn .msg').each(function () {
    w = Math.max(w, $(this).width());
});

$('.btn').width(w);

var h = 0;
$('.btn .msg').each(function () {
    h = Math.max(h, $(this).height());
});

$('.btn').height(h);
```

But now the `.msg` spans are arranged vertically. To compensate for that, depends on what you what to achieve. One solution is to use `position: absolute`

```css
.btn {
    position: relative;
}
.btn-status .msg {
    position: absolute;
}
```

The `.msg` spans are now lying on top of each other. You must also adjust the vertical transformation.

See modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V9yTs/7/)